# Omnidirectional refraction of a ray light

Tags: optics, reflection, refraction

Is there such a material or construction of refractors or reflectors such that a ray or rays of light entering into the medium are redirected so as to exit the medium in a nearly all directions? For instance if the material were made to be a sphere and you shined a laser or flashlight into it perpendicular to the surface of the sphere that the sphere would “glow” (radiate the refracted light into all directions or very nearly all directions) with low losses due to the medium such that the majority of the light exits the medium as if it were radiated from approximately the center of the sphere?

Comment: what is the practical problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I’m trying to scatter light in such a way as to illuminate the inside of a sphere as evenly as possible using directed light rays entering from one direction through a hole in the top of the sphere; rays entering into the sphere can be assumed to be parallel to each other.

Comment: Conceivably a diverging lens may be used to illuminate a portion of the sphere, perhaps a whole hemisphere but I’m curious if there is a way to illuminate the entire sphere using light from one direction as it would simplify the construction greatly.

Comment: @WattMilliams I'm an idiot sorry, diverging lens won't do the job. Would a pinhole be effective as it acts like a point source of light? I'm not sure if it would be bright enough though.

Comment: Hmmm it’s possible to use a concave parabolic reflector to focus light it enter through a pinhole such that the focus of the mirror lies exactly in the pinhole and as the rays of light diverge pass the focus it would allow light to scatter as a cone sharply and that would illuminate the majority of the interior of sphere in that setup. You’re not an idiot btw. Thank for taking time to even reply to me!